# ASP.NET: User won't stay logged in for more than 30 mins

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

This is really irritating me, and is probably causing the waning usership on my website. I'm using Forms Authentication to log my user in.

I have the "Persist" parameter set to true by default when the user logs in:

```
RedirectFromLoginPage(userString, True)
```

and

```
SetAuthCookie(userString, True)
```

In my web.Config file I have the "timeout" attribute set to "129600":

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="/registration/login.aspx"
    timeout="129600" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

I called my hosting company and they said the problem has to be with my code. I don't believe this is the case.

What the #(*@%&@(#*%&@(#*% could be wrong??

**EDIT** This used to work fine until I switched hosts. That led me to believe that it was not my code, but in fact the host.

**EDIT 2** In response to a comment to use Fiddler, here's what I get from Fiddler when I load the page:

```
Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=; expires=Tue, 12-Oct-1999 07:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=[some gobbledygook]; 
  expires=Sun, 15-Nov-2009 20:46:29 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=vudqghfplqnh5hz1qw1cwebt; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Answer (score 3):

Your app pool could be recycling - either on some set time period, or based on a threshold on memory or processor.  If it used to work fine, and nothing else changed, I think that would be where I would investigate first.

Comment: is this something the host controls?

Comment: Yes.  See this for IIS6 - http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1eee28e2-b319-4b4e-8267-a8c0aa0dcf36.mspx?mfr=true and this for IIS7 - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753179(WS.10).aspx.

Comment: ugh... my host is godaddy... guess this problem isn't going away any time soon...

Comment: This should not log you out.  Session state is succeptible to this if inproc is used.  But forms auth is not session state based - it's just a cookie...

Comment: Having said that - if the machinekey in the machine level web.config is set to autogenerate then the encryption key for the .aspxauth cookie will change after restart, invalidating the cookie.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things that could be causing a timeout.  [This Blog](http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/07/aspnet-session-timeouts.html) provides a great overview.

Comment: This article talks about session state - this has nothing to do with forms auth an the .aspxauth cookie.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Fiddler to verify the expiration date set on the cookie that comes back from the login page.

Comment: why won't the second cookie stay?

Answer (score 1):

As you know I have a similar problem. What might be happening is the application pool is [shutting down](http://community.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/idle-time-out-in-the-application-pool/).

Do a test: open your session in 2 different browsers and in one of them reload the web page in less than 20 minutes, while in the other do nothing.

What might happen is that you won't get logged off of any of them because the app pool is kept alive.

edit:

Try this: http://authors.aspalliance.com/paulwilson/articles/?id=12

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this behavior for me is usually the IIS Idle Timeout.

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to use [sessionstate timeout](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t114932-is-sessionstate-timeout-the-same-as-login-timeout.html).